# PDF file size from document directory showing zero in iOS

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I am retrieving file size of PDF file that located in document directory with following codes.

```
- (NSString *)sizeOfFile:(NSString *)filePath {
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    NSInteger fileSize = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize] integerValue];
    NSString *fileSizeString = [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:fileSize countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile];
    return fileSizeString;
}



NSURL *url = [self.arrayOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",[self sizeOfFile:url.absoluteString]); // Showing zero KB.
```

I am sure there is file in `arrayBooks` because it can show in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

But i don't know why file size is showing zero.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you verified that `filePath` actually exists? Have you verified that `fileAttributes` isn't `nil`? Use the `error` parameter to `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`.

Comment: fileAttributes is showing nil. But filePath is correct.

Comment: Again, use the `error` parameter to see why `fileAttributes` is `nil`.

Comment: Error message is . 

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x10934b640 {NSFilePath=file:///Users/user/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/08BE9071-6251-44ED-A8E0-55CD478380FC/Documents/myPDFFile.pdf, NSUnderlyingError=0x10934b170 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of your issue is due to an invalid path being sent to `sizeOfFile:`.

Your code:

```
NSURL *url = [self.arrayOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",[self sizeOfFile:url.absoluteString]); // Showing zero KB.
```

should be:

```
NSURL *url = [self.arrayOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",[self sizeOfFile:[url path]]);
```

You want to call the `path` method to get a file path. `absoluteString` returns a file URL, not a path.

Also, don't use property syntax to call methods.

Comment: Thanks you. Now i got. I don't understand don't use property syntax to call method.Why i shouldn't use it.Please could you explain?